# Can I make the running process to be visible?

Tags: 12.04

I'm doing this : `sudo unattended-upgrade`. It is running and its showing blank screen. It is taking time. I just want the process to been seen visibly ( i.e it downloads and other stuffs). Is that possible with any command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `--debug` parameter.

```
sudo unattended-upgrade --debug
```

---

Example output:

```
Initial blacklisted packages:
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=oneiric-security']
pkgs that look like they should be upgraded:
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
blacklist: []
InstCount=0 DelCount=0 BrokenCout=0
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended
```